# Why is the console coming out differently in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, scrollview, scrollbar, use-effect, console.log

I wanted to make sure that the scroll was located in the middle of the area in case of scrolling.

```
const scrollRef = useScroll(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const wrapper = scrollRef.current;
    console.dir(wrapper, 'wrapper');
    if (wrapper) {
      const hasScroll = wrapper.scrollHeight > wrapper.clientHeight;
      console.log(wrapper.scrollHeight, 'scrollheight');
      console.log(wrapper.clientHeight, 'clientHeight');
      if (hasScroll) {
        const scrollTop = (wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.clientHeight) / 2;
        wrapper.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      }
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <TradeSection>
        <Loader />
      </TradeSection>
    );
  }

<Section>
  <TableHeader>
  <TableList ref={scrollRef}>
    <List />
    <CurrentPrice />
    <List />
  </TableList>
<Section>
```

This code works well in general.
but sometime it doesnt't work
According to my guess, if you refresh after the screen size changes,
so i add console in useEffect

[image]
[image]

why console.dir > scrollHeight is different result ?
Why do you show different values in the same area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is not updating when the current ref value changes. This means that your console log fires whenever `isLoading` updates, but does not capture the final value of `scrollRef.current`.

Putting something inside a `useEffect` is only helpful if the `useEffect` can actually keep track of changes to that value. Unfortunately, that is not possible with `useRef` because an object ref does not notify your component about changes to the current ref value. For this use case, the correct hook is actually `useCallback`; see this [React FAQ answer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) for an explanation and a somewhat similar example.